# How to build my lambda with a custom image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

When I build my lambdas with this command:

```
sam build --use-container -t infrastructure.yml
```

How I specify a custom image (default is amazon/aws-sam-cli-build-image-python3.8)

Answer (score 0):

SAM offers a option to skip the pull image, so will search for local images. So, create a image with the default name local and pass the option `--skip-pull-image`

```
docker pull MY_IMAGE

docker image tag MY_IMAGE amazon/aws-sam-cli-build-image-python3.8
sam build --use-container --skip-pull-image ...
```